# Virtual Page View with Google Tag Manager Not Triggering

Tags: google-tag-manager

On a page I try to fire a virtual page view through Google Tag Manager. I have

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
dataLayer.push({
'event':'sendVirtualPageview',
'vpv':'/goals/sale-product'
});
});
</script>
```

In tag manager, I've created a new container for the same universal analytics with:
- "Document Path" of "{{vpv}}"
- a firing rule of: Send Virtual Pageview {{vpv}} equals sendVirtualPageview.
- a Data Layer Variable macro name and data layer variable name of "vpv" with data layer version 1.

The rule is not firing in debug mode. Ideas of what could be going on?

I assume Google Tag Manager has to be included before this code?

**Update of What I Have:**

```
<script>dataLayer = [{ 'vpv': '/goals/sale-product', }];</script>
```

**Tag**

```
Tag Name: Google Analytics Sale
Tag Type: Universal Analytics
Tracking ID: UA-XXXXXX-XX
Track Type: Event
Category: Virtual Page View
Action: {{vpv}}
```

**Rule**

```
Rule Name: Send Virtual Pageview Sale
{{vpv}} equals /goals/sale-product
```

**Macro**

```
Macro Name: vpv
Macro Type: Data Layer Variable
Data Layer Variable Name: vpv
Data Layer Version: Version 1
```

Rule is tied to the tag. Tag not firing.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm reading your question right.

You're trying to track within Google Tag Manager when a user hits a specific URL, and then push that URL to Google Analytics?

Here's a way to go about it:

## 1. Create a dataLayer object that pushes the current url (place this before the google tag manager initialize script)

```
    var currentPage = (document.URL);
    var lastSegment = currentPage.split('/').pop();
    dataLayer = [{
        'pageURL': lastSegment,
    }];
```

## 2. Set up a `rule` in GTM that will fire whenever you hit the appropriate URL.

```
Rule Name: URL Fire

Conditions:
{{url}} contains whateveryoururlis.com
```

This can be as specific as you want. If you only want it to fire when your site is in /goals/ just do:

```
Rule Name: URL Fire

Conditions:
{{url}} contains /goals/
```

## 3. Create a `Macro` that will push the dataLayer pageURL object.

```
Macro Name: Push URL
Macro Type: Data Layer Variable
Data Layer Variable Name: pageURL
```

## 4.Hook this rule + macro up to a `Tag` that will trigger on the current page that will push the current page url to a Google Analytics event:

```
Tag Name: URL Analytics

Tag Type: Universal Analytics

Tracking ID: Your ID

Firing Rules: URL Fire (The one you created above)

Track Type: Event

Category: Virtual Page View

Action: {{Push URL}}
```

## This Tag should fire whenever you hit the URL you set up in #2 and push the pageURL dataLayer variable set up in #3.

Comment: Yes, very close to what I'm asking except for a single url. What should the full html code be if the dataLayer object is just one url?
    `<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ dataLayer.push({ 'pageURL':'/goals/sale-product' }); });
</script>`

Comment: @Joshua You could use a blocking rule if the URL didn't contain: /goals/sale-product

Comment: and then remove the  var lastSegment = currentPage.split('/').pop(); so it would capture the entire URL

Comment: Can you spell it out for me by providing the code? I've ran through it in debug mode like 30 times and the tag doesn't fire. I'm using the code in my comment above that doesn't include the var lastSegment.

Comment: Sorry, it's not jQuery. Here's a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/9cNVT/2/

<script>
    var currentPage = (document.URL);
    dataLayer = [{
        'pageURL': currentPage,
    }];
</script>

Comment: I am able to replicate the JSfiddle on the site. The debug mode is still telling me the tag is not firing. I have another tag with the UA firing on all pages and both tags are published. Further ideas? No warnings or errors in Firebug.

Comment: Sorry, the above should work. Can't really help any further without seeing a URL + your GTM and seeing what's actually going on

Comment: {{url}} equals /goals/sale-product should be {{url}} contains /goals/sale-product

Comment: {{url}} means the actual url of the domain. If you want it to fire based on your dataLayer you're going to have to create a rule that checks against the dataLayer variable

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I've updated it (and the code in the original post) and it's still not firing. Google have updated the information supplied in the debug mode! I see the main UA tag is not firing on this particular page. Wow. The main UA tag fires on all other pages I've tested. When removing `<script>dataLayer = [{ 'vpv': '/goals/sale-product', }];</script>`, the main UA tag fires on this page.

Comment: I eventually got this to work. The in-page code needs to be: `<script>dataLayer.push({'event':'sendVirtualPageView', 'vpv':'/goals/sale-product'});</script>` and for some reason, I didn't have an event macro, which I then created.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand,  in your example you should use {{event}} equals sendVirtualPageview.

Comment: There is no macro {{event}}.